# Taylor Rule Smoothing

Tags: stata

I have an equation of the following kind, a standard Taylor rule with a smoothing parameter:
e(t) = p * e(t-1) + (1-p) * (a * pi + b * y).

e(t-1) is just the lagged interest rate, weighted by p, and pi and y are the relevant independent variables inflation and output gap.

I have started with simple OLS regressions including three independent variables e(t-1), pi and y. As a second step, I advanced to GMM IV regressions, given the following command in Stata:

ivregress gmm euribor (inflation L1.euribor ygap = ...[IVs]).

However, the resulting coefficients in both versions are not the ones for p, a and b of the function in the first line. This is because I am missing the (1-p) part, weighting the second part of the equation. So far, my function is a simple

e(t) = p * e(t-1) + a * pi + b * y

One way get to the wanted results is to regress this, manually calulate (1-p) and eventually divide the resulted a and b by (1-p). However, I would like to find a Stata command that includes this directly.

I have tried with constraint define sum_coefficients, but I could not work it out.

Comment: I don't know how people get that, as p, a and b need to be determined at the same time. Perhaps it is by search on in (p, a, b) space. What is obvious to you isn't obvious to me. And you have instrumental variables too?

Comment: The function could be modeled as e = p * e(t-1) + a * pi + b * y in an ordninary regression with OLS coefficients p, a and b for the dependent variables e(t-1), pi and y. The instrumental variables can bee added or left out, this does not matter at this point.

What I can do with the results of this OLS is the following: I can weight the (a* pi + b * y) part with (1-p) manually, using the OLS resulted p. The idea is to get results for a and b isolated from the continuation/smoothing factor. Does this clear things up?

Comment: But you have lost (1 - p) in that formulation, which is perhaps your question, and sorry, I don't have an answer. You need an answer from someone who knows what people do in this field.

Comment: exactly that's the point, the way I am doing it so far loses (1-p) in the equation. I do not not how I can include this in the STATA regression function however, this is why I am asking for help

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible solutions to your question.

(1) If you merely want to compute the weights in two steps, the best way to do this is to use a loop.  With the loop, you can run the first regression, have Stata predict *p*, then plug *p* into your (1 - *p*) calculation, and finally rerun the regression.

The loop structure will allow you to designate *p* as a variable, which will potentially change with each iteration that you run.  Running the loop will be more efficient than running the calculations by hand each time.

Note, however, that I don't recommend EITHER computing the weights by hand OR using the loop structure. Regardless of method, your errors -- based on a two-step calculation -- will be biased.

For more information on this bias, read this:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1391724.pdf?refreqid=fastly-default%3A7105fad5ad1516541a44f6b285fa2535&ab_segments=&origin=&initiator=&acceptTC=1

(2) For the information that you need with unbiased errors, you need to have Stata compute the weights simultaneously.  If you are not a confident coder, the simplest way to do this is to multiply out your entire equation, run the regression long-form, then recombine coefficients to determine the final weights.

In other words, multiply this out:
(1-p) * (a * pi + b * y)

To be:
(a * pi + b * y) - [p * (a * pi + b * y)]
[(a * pi + b * y) - (p * a * pi) + (p * b * y)]

Then sum with:
[p * e(t-1)]

To equal:
e(t) = [p * e(t-1) + a * pi + b * y - p * a * pi + p * b * y]

This will give you a simple linear equation that you can run.

(3) If your coding skills are okay, the best method is to  run your model as a non-linear equation so that your error terms will be unbiased.  To see how to do this, read:

https://www.stata.com/manuals/rnl.pdf